# How to Authentication Google App Engine using service account in python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE application written in python which serves serving_url() for images stored in google cloud storage of that project only and that is works properly. But the problem is when I'm trying to get serving url from different project (google storage) then it throws error AccessDenied. I'm new to pythonas well as google cloud so can anyone suggest me how can I authenticate to get serving_url() for the image which are stored in some other project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your different project's Service Accounts, with email similar to yourDifferent@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, as members with 'Editor' permission on the project that initially owns the GCS bucket you want to access. This can be done on the IAM page of the project that owns the bucket: https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=yourDifferent (replace "yourDifferent" with the name of your different project).

More detail on service accounts may be gathered from the [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) documentation page.